# The @Override annotation is shown as deprecated in a new project created in android

Tags: java, android, overriding, deprecated

I created a new project in Android Studio and it shows `@Override` for all methods as deprecated. This also happen when I open existing projects. Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix it?

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've accidentally marked the interface as deprecated - there's a Studio quickfix that makes it easy.

Locate the `java/lang/annotations.xml` file somewhere in your filesystem (where you saved it when applying the quickfix), and remove the following there:

```
<item name='java.lang.Override'>
    <annotation name='java.lang.Deprecated' />
</item>
```